# How to run/call a flask app inside another flask app

Tags: python, html, flask, url, localhost

I have three working flask apps - app1.py, app2.py and app3.py . I want to make an index app called index.py that has links to the three apps and can call or run them when i want.
Is it possible for all 4 of the apps to run on the same host?
I should be able to see links to the three apps on my index app and be able to launch them on their respective html websites by app routing and render template.

```
Directory -
/Flask
   /templates
       index.html
       app1.html
       app2.html
       app3.html
  index.py
  app1.py
  app2.py
  app3.py
```

I've tried importing the three files into index.py and then calling them but it doesnt work.
I've also tried URL redirecting when all 4 apps have different hosts but it too doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to serve multiple applications. Not so much information, but when you try to run multiple apps on one host, you can run them on different ports and address them like this http://some-domain-name:8000 etc.

Also you can use a reverse proxy like nginx to do the routing like this:

```
http://some-domain-name/app1 -> localhost:8000
http://some-domain-name/app2 -> localhost:8001
```

or something.

If you provide more use cases it would be easy to help you.

Comment: Thanks. I used different ports for all three apps and then in the index app, i used the subprocess module to run the apps on their respective ports. It works.